# Why does getaddrinfo return ipv6 address instead of cname in ai_cannonname?

Tags: c, dns, ipv6

My code has:

```
hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
ret_ga = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &res);
```

When hostname is ipv6.google.com, 
res->ai_canonname is returning 2607:f8b0:4005:802::1006.

I expected/want the cname
ipv6.l.google.com.

When I try this on ipv4.google.com, I get the cname nuq05s02-in-f9.1e100.net.

Do I need to set some other ai_flags in order to get the cname for ipv6.google.com?

Comment: On what type of system? This is probably a bug. IPv6 and `ai_canonname` are both things that tend to be a buggy on a lot of implementations of `getaddrinfo`... :(

Comment: Do you know what libc, or third-party implementation of `getaddrinfo`, it's using? Is it bare-metal or running on Linux or another existing kernel?

Comment: It's uClibc that's several years old - I'm sure you are right that it has a bug.